# Bar on the side of the heading

Tags: html, css

I can't figure this one out. I have a heading (H1) and a colored bar on the right side of the heading. The bar should always cover the area between end of the heading and end of the content area. Something like that:

LOREM IPSUM ================================================

LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET =================================

At this point, everything works fine. HTML:

```
<h1>LOREM IPSUM</h1><hr/>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

and CSS:

```
h1 { float: left; margin: 0 10px 0 0; font-size: 18px; }
hr { display: block; border-top: 18px solid green; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XEhLm/)

Problem is that this approach doesn't work with **multiline heading**, it would be perfect to have something like this (so the colored bar appears on the last row):

LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT.

PROIN SAGITTIS DICTUM RISUS A DAPIBUS ========================

Any ideas? :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XEhLm/8/)

HTML:

```
<h1><span>LOREM IPSUM<br />TEST</span></h1>
<div class="clear"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris odio magna, rhoncus sed leo et, dapibus adipiscing metus. Donec cursus dignissim ipsum sit amet suscipit.</p>
```

CSS:

```
h1 { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 10px 0 0; 
    font-size: 18px; 
    display:block; 
    background:green; 
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
}

h1 span {
    background:#FFF;
    padding-right:10px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.clear { clear: both; }
```

Comment: Thank you, but 1) this needs <br> tag in the heading and 2) the colored bar is on both rows (not on the last). Without inline-block on h1 span, it's almost there: http://jsfiddle.net/uf2ze/
(but there's still bar on the first row)